# Disproving a statement about connectedness.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $X \subset M$ is connected and $M$ is a metric space with $d(y,z) = 2$, for $y,z \in X$. Must there be an $x \in X$, such that $d(x,z) = 1$?

I know I am supposed to get a contradiction, but I can't find it because I am used to understanding connectedness is a topological feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If there were no such $x$, then $$X=(X\cap A)\cup(X\cap B)$$
where $$A=\{p\in M : d(p,z)<1\}$$ $$B=\{p\in M : d(p,z)>1\}$$
are open sets of $M$ meeting $X$.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that there is no such point. Show that the open ball $B(z,1)$ is also closed but not all of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't really see where this method is heading towards…

Comment: @sidht: You know that $B(z,1)$ is open and non-empty. If it’s also closed and not all of $X$, then its complement is also open and non-empty, and the clopen sets $B(z,1)$ and $X\setminus B(z,1)$ separate $X$; thus, $X$ is not connected. This is exactly the same separation as was given explicitly by MPW.

Answer (score 1):

The distance function is always continuous in the topology induced by the metric. The image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected. Therefore ...

Comment: I thought of that too, and I tried assuming using the connectedness of $[a,b]$ in $\Bbb R$

Comment: If both 2 and 0 lie in the (connected) image, then so must 1. Thus there is a point which maps to 1.